# How to put custom structure to stack and then be able to access all fields?

Tags: syntax, go

I have struct Foo with fields Field_1 and Field_2.

```
  package foo  
  type Custom struct {
      start_row int
      start_column int
      move_row int
      move_column int
    }

    type Foo struct{
      Field_1 [100]Custom
      Field_2 stack.Stack
    }
```

How can I initialize Foo? Something like this,

```
new_element := &foo.Foo { [100]foo.Custom{}, stack.Stack {} }
```

But I need specify stack as container for foo.Custom struct, because I need to access later start_row, start_column like this

```
Element: = Field_2.Pop()
fmt.Printf("%d \n", Element.start_row)
```

Here is stack implementation

```
package stack

type Stack struct {
  top *Element
  size int
}

type Element struct {
  value interface{}
  next *Element
}

// Get length of the stack
func (s *Stack) Length() int {
  return s.size
}

// Push a new element into the stack
func (s *Stack) Push(value interface{}) {
  s.top = &Element{value, s.top}
  s.size += 1
}

// Remove the top element from the stack and return value
// If stack is empty return nil
func (s *Stack) Pop() (value interface{}) {
  if s.size > 0 {
    value, s.top = s.top.value, s.top.next
    s.size -= 1
    return
  }
  return nil
}
```

Comment: Normally in Go you just use a `[]MyType` as a "stack". The builtin `append` is "push" and you either grab the last element or the first for LIFO or FIFO semantics (e.g. `x, s = s[len(s)-1], s[:len(s)-1]` or `x, s = s[0], s[1:]`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few points:

1. all fields in `Custom` are not exported, you can't modify them directly from a different package.
2. You can't create `Foo` that way, however since it's an array you can simply just use `new_element := &foo.Foo{Field_2: Stack{}}`.

Comment: Field_2 is not an array. I need to create Field_2 as a stack of a specific type, because later I need to Pop() element from stack and access "start_row ", "start_column ".

Comment: You need to be more specific then, where's that stack package defined?

Answer (score 0):

With the current implementation of package stack, there is no way to enforce the type of `value` that gets stored inside struct `Element`.

Comment: Maybe something like this - https://play.golang.org/p/Ftrm8V3-9a

You can separate those out into different packages